# C#/Xamarin Save max read value of Variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm continually writing values to a variable and would like a separate variable to keep track of the max value that the first variable reaches. Searches of 'saving variable max value' returns a lot of info about maximum values that variable types can represent as one would expect.

Would like for it to look something like:

```
while (device == connected)
{
     float x = (float) read.device(1);
     float maxvalue = 0.00;
     if (x > maxvalue)
     {
          maxvalue = max(x); //max() is a function I'd like to implement if one isn't already available
     }
}
```

Obviously the syntax is not correct in this example but I showed it to get the general idea of what I was looking for.

The value for x is continually changing up to 30 times per second and I only want to keep track of the highest value it has seen since entering the while loop. This seems simple and I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: You need to show us the code for the `max(x)` function? Unless you just meant to write `maxvalue = x;`?

Comment: And, do you also not mean `while (device == connected)`? I don't think you've posted your real code. Can you please post your real code?

Comment: @Enigmativity I suppose that's what I was getting at when I said it wasn't the correct syntax. There is no real code because I can't figure it out. I did mean both of things you mentioned though. This is the first program/app I've ever made and have never used c#.

Answer (score 3):

Move the declaration out of the loop and then 2 choices:

```
if (x > maxvalue) maxvalue = x;
```

or

```
maxvalue = Math.Max(maxvalue, x);
```

Now you reset maxvalue to 0.0 in every iteration so every value > 0 becomes maxvalue.

So

```
float maxvalue = 0.00;
while (device == connected)
{
     float x = (float) read.device(1);     
     maxvalue = Math.Max(maxvalue, x);
}
```

I recommend using Math.Max always instead of if statement as as it also handles corner cases for floats like NaN.

Comment: Ah that was the problem! Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is no overload of `Math.Max` that takes one parameter. You really don't need to use this function anyway. You've explained it above and then failed to use it below.

Comment: @Enigmativity My issue was that the maxvalue declaration was in the while loop. Moving it outside made it perform as expected. I didn't use the Math.Max function at all.

Comment: @BME - That's good, but the answer is for all users of this site. It should be clear to them too.

Comment: changed math.max into two parameters. Math.Max is better than using if directly as it also handles corner cases for floats like NaN

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

```
float maxvalue = 0.0f;
while (device == connected)
{
    float x = (float)read.device(1);
    if (x > maxvalue)
    {
        maxvalue = x;
    }
}
```

or:

```
float maxvalue = 0.0f;
while (device == connected)
{
    float x = (float)read.device(1);
    maxvalue = Math.Max(maxvalue, x);
}
```

or:

```
float maxvalue = 0.0f;
while (device == connected)
{
    float x = (float)read.device(1);
    maxvalue = x > maxvalue ? x : maxvalue;
}
```

or make `IEnumerable<float>` method:

```
public IEnumerable<float> DeviceValues()
{
    while (device == connected)
    {
        yield return (float)read.device(1);
    }
}
```

Then it's just:

```
float maxvalue = DeviceValues().Max();
```